# Cannot Get This Disk Image To Mount!

Tags: custom-roms, rom

I am trying to download the firmware for the RikoMagic MK802 IV, which can be found [here](http://www.rikomagic.com/en/product/showpro_id_39_pid_19.html). After it finishes downloading, I want to open it up and begin modifying it a bit for fun, but nothing I do seems to work. I've tried opening it with `ext2/ext4` explorers and unpackers, I've tried mounting the disk image file in Ubuntu and Windows, I've tried using everything I could in Android Kitchen, and nothing seems to be able to get this open and editable. Any ideas what else I could try? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I picked one of those downloads at random and looked at the `.img` file inside the `.rar` archive.  It's a proprietary format.  `file` and `trid` have no idea what type it's supposed to be, the former just says "data".  The first four characters of the file are `RKFW`, presumably for **R**i**k**o **f**irm**w**are.

[GeekPeek.net](https://geekpeek.net/unpack-rikomagic-firmware/) has a pretty good guide on how to unpack and repack these files using the `imgRePackerRK` tool from [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2257331).